# how to make config fields stick at admin/structure/types/manage/<content_type>?

Tags: 7, forms

I am adding a config option to all content types. I have textfield and checkbox now.

How to SAVE what I write in the textfield and state of checkbox when I hit submit?? Do I need to alter submit function for this form?

```
function neil_misc_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  global $user;
  if (isset($form['type'])) {
    $form['followbtn'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Follow Button settings'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => TRUE,
      '#group' => 'additional_settings',
    );

$form['followbtn']['comment'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Email address to send updates to'),
  '#default_value' => $user->mail,
);

$form['followbtn']['followbtn_default_mode'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Add Follow button to this Node Type?'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('comment_default_mode_' . $form['#node_type']->type, ADD_FOLLOWBTN),
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom submit handler for your custom group of options and controls. For example on the base form you add an additional `#submit` value and check your own custom fields:

```
$form['#submit'][] = array('mymodule_form_followbtn_custom_submit');
```

if needed you can validate is form element independantley:

```
$form['followbtn']['followbtn_default_mode']['#element_validate'] = 'mymodule_followbtn_element_validate_default_mode';
```

or ...

```
$form['followbtn']['comment'] = 'mymodule_followbtn)element_validate_comment';
```

Then your submit function just does your processing (after elements validate on submission:

```
function mymodule_form_followbtn_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // save your stuff ...
}
```